# Why is Wine X11 not creating a window on my Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, x11, wine

I have the wine software on my mac and I have a little problem here:

I try running my windows executable and I get this error in the console:

`Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded. make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 126`

I have my DISPLAY set to 0.0 and WINEPREFIX set to x.

Please show me how to fix this with exact code/steps because I am new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: What OS version are you using? Are you trying to launch from Terminal.app?

Comment: Mac OS 10.6.6 I am trying to run windows executables.

Comment: and I am running it by just double clicking it. and it opens WineHelper

Answer (score 1):

You don't have X11 installed on your computer. It is available on the OS X install CD.

Comment: If he was able to install Wine, he has X11. Unless he opted out of installing it. @DantheMan  Do you have the X11 application in Applications>Utlities?

Comment: I had the same kind of error and it turned out I didn't have X11 installed.

Answer (score 0):

See [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/216999/display-set-incorrectly) DISPLAY on OSX is not 0.0 . It is set by the startup and you should not set the variable manually.